# Failed to load dynamic library in Flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, android-ndk

I have a Flutter app in production on the Google Play store, which includes a native dynamic library built using the NDK and loaded at runtime (I have called it `libraster.so`). On most devices this library is present and loads fine. But on certain devices, the following `ArgumentError` occurs at runtime `Invalid argument(s): Failed to load dynamic library (dlopen failed: library "libraster.so" not found)`.

The devices in question are ARM devices I believe. The app doesn't specify any `abiFilter` in the app module's `build.gradle` file.

Using Google Play Console's App Bundle Explorer, I can download the APKs that would be distributed to the affected devices, and they contain `libraster.so` as normal.

According to my error logs, the device which are affected so far are:

| Model | Name | Android version |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SM-G928F | Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge+ | 6.0.1 |
| SM-J500M | Samsung Galaxy J5 | 6.0.1 |
| SM-J710GN | Samsung Galaxy J7 2016 | 6.0.1 |
| SM-T110 | Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 Lite 7.0 | 4.2.2 |
| SM-T111M | Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 Lite 7.0 | 4.2.2 |
| GT-I8262 | Samsung Galaxy Core Duos | 4.1.2 |
| GT-I8552 | Samsung Galaxy Win Duos | 4.1.2 |
| GT-I8552B | Samsung Galaxy Win Duos | 4.1.2 |
| GT-I9082L | Samsung Galaxy Grand Duos | 4.2.2 |
| GT-I9300 | Samsung Galaxy S III | 4.1.2 |
| GT-N8000 | Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 | 4.1.2 |
| GT-N8010 | Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 | 4.1.2 |
| GT-P3110 | Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 7.0 | 4.1.2 |
| GT-P5110 | Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 10.1 | 4.2.2 |
| SO-03E | Sony Xperia Tablet Z | 4.1.2 |
| B1-A71 | Acer Iconia Tab B1-A71 | 4.1.2 |
| F-01F | Fujitsu Arrows NX F-01F | 4.2.2 |
| ME173X | Asus Memo Pad HD7 | 4.2.2 |

Mostly Android 4.1.2, 4.2.2 and 6.0.1 devices.

Here's a simplified version of my app module's `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.package"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        multiDexEnabled true

        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                arguments "-DCOMPILE_TESTS:BOOL=OFF"
            }
        }

        // Maintains debug symbols
        packagingOptions {
          doNotStrip '**.so'
        }
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release

            minifyEnabled true
            useProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

            ndk {
                debugSymbolLevel = 'FULL'
            }
        }
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            version "3.19.2"
            path "path/to/CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And `proguard-rules.pro`:

```
#Flutter Wrapper
-keep class io.flutter.app.** { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.plugin.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.util.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.view.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.plugins.**  { *; }
-dontwarn io.flutter.embedding.**

-keep class com.example.package.** { *; }
```

The Flutter version used is stable `1.22.5`.

Is this a bug in Flutter? Do these devices load dynamic libraries differently to other devices? Is `libraster.so` just actually not being packaged with the APK in some scenarios?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A similar issue was reported here: https://github.com/simolus3/moor/issues/895

The suggested fix was for this case to create a Flutter plugin which calls System.loadLibrary()

Comment: Thank you, yes that was the solution I ended up going with, as suggested by a Dart team member: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/73318#issuecomment-754598119

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old issue, but I ran into this issue recently and I solved it by adding [sqlite3_flutter_libs](https://pub.dev/packages/sqlite3_flutter_libs/install) as a dependency in pub spec.yaml

```
dependencies:
   moor: ^4.3.0
   sqlite3_flutter_libs: ^0.4.2
```

Answer (score 0):

here are a solution thanks to [knaeckeKami](https://github.com/knaeckeKami).

first, you need to create a plugin:

```kotlin
package <your_package>

import android.content.Context
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo
import android.content.pm.PackageManager

import androidx.annotation.NonNull

import io.flutter.embedding.engine.plugins.FlutterPlugin
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodCall
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.Result
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.Registrar

class Plugin: FlutterPlugin, MethodCallHandler {
  companion object {
    const val TAG = <YOUR_TAG>
  }

  private lateinit var channel: MethodChannel
  private lateinit var context: Context

  override fun onAttachedToEngine(@NonNull flutterPluginBinding: FlutterPlugin.FlutterPluginBinding) {
    context = flutterPluginBinding.applicationContext
    channel = MethodChannel(flutterPluginBinding.binaryMessenger, <CHANNEL_NAME>)

    channel.setMethodCallHandler(this)
  }

  override fun onMethodCall(@NonNull call: MethodCall, @NonNull result: Result) {
    if (call.method == "getNativeLibraryDirectory") {
      val applicationInfo: ApplicationInfo = context.packageManager.getApplicationInfo(context.packageName, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA)

      if (applicationInfo != null) {
        result.success(applicationInfo.nativeLibraryDir)
      } else {
        result.success(null)
      }
    } else {
      result.notImplemented()
    }
  }

  override fun onDetachedFromEngine(@NonNull binding: FlutterPlugin.FlutterPluginBinding) {
    channel.setMethodCallHandler(null)
  }
}
```

then you can use `_getAndroidDynamicLibrary(String libraryName)` instead of `DynamicLibrary.open(libraryName)` to load your library:

```dart
Future<DynamicLibrary> _getAndroidDynamicLibrary(String libraryName) async {
  try {
    return DynamicLibrary.open(libraryName);
  } catch (_) {
    try {
      final String? nativeLibraryDirectory = await _getNativeLibraryDirectory();

      return DynamicLibrary.open('$nativeLibraryDirectory/$libraryName');
    } catch (_) {
      try {
        final PackageInfo packageInfo = await PackageInfo.fromPlatform();
        final String packageName = packageInfo.packageName;

        return DynamicLibrary.open('/data/data/$packageName/lib/$libraryName');
      } catch (_) {
        rethrow;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

usage:

```dart
Future<DynamicLibrary> _getNativeAppTokenLibrary() async => Platform.isAndroid
    ? await _getAndroidDynamicLibrary(_libraryName)
    : DynamicLibrary.process();
```